# Spacetime dilation Moon vs Earth

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, observers

As I understand it, time will pass slightly faster on the surface of the moon compared to the earth

This is due to the difference in velocity and gravitational fields of the two planets.

How could I calculate the difference between a "Moon Second" and an "Earth Second" with as much accuracy as possible? (resulting in a difference something like 10^-12 seconds)

EDIT: An alternative way to describe my question is this: Place one atomic clock on the earth and one on the moon for 1 year. When both clocks are brought back to earth, what would the time difference be between the clocks?

EDIT 2: Solution

To calculate the time dilation, I used two formulas:

1) Gravitational time dilation from Allure's answer $t_0 = t_f \sqrt{1- \frac{2GM}{rc^2}}$

2) Time dilation caused by velocity $t_0=sqrt(1−v^2/c^2)$

With each I calculated the moon and earth solutions separately (getting always 0.999999 type numbers), then divided earth by moon to get the relative time dilation. Finally, I converted this into seconds per year.

The gravitational pull creates ~0.02096.... seconds per year. The velocity creates an additional 52.87... microseconds. So the final time dilation is around 21.0140431070800... milliseconds per year.

This is just the numbers I got and may not be correct. Hopefully it is useful to someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small technical point: given there's no objective way to measure time you can't actually calculate the difference between a "Moon second" and an "Earth second", unless you're comparing them to an observer at infinite distance.

You need the formula for [gravitational time dilation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation). Given that the Moon and the Earth are both approximately spherical, you can approximate them with the Schwarzschild metric, and the formula is:

$t_0 = t_f \sqrt{1- \frac{2GM}{rc^2}}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I made an edit which describes the problem using atomic clocks. Isn't that kind of an objective measuring tool? (minus the time inteference when migrating the moon clock back to earth)

Comment: I think the Schwarzschild metric might be a little out of my depth. If anyone has any insight on how to apply it to the moon that'd be very helpful

Comment: The formula you get is in the answer already ...

Comment: @Slidon The above comment is for you

Comment: @Slidon the problem is not in the clocks. You need to define a way you compare them because they are not located in the same place. One way is that both clocks fire a laser signal each "tick" and a distand observer compares them. But it's not unique and other waus would give different answers